# Proof of Pentagonal Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that $P$ is a pentagonal number if and only if $\sqrt{24P + 1} ≡ 5\mod 6$

Proof:

The pentagonal numbers can be found from the formula:

$P = \frac{3}{2}n^2 - \frac{1}{2}n$

That is:

$0 = \frac{3}{2}n^2 - \frac{1}{2} - P$

$ 0 = 3n^2 -n - 2P$

$n = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$

$n = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{(-1)^2 - 4(3)(-2p)}}{2(3)}$

$n = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+24p}}{6}$

That means $n$ is divisible by $6$ or in other words

$1 \pm \sqrt{1+24p} ≡ 0 \mod 6$

$\sqrt{1+24p} ≡ 5 \mod 6$

I believe this means that I only proved the statement one way though. For the other way would I have to start at $\sqrt{24P + 1} ≡ 5 \mod 6$ and work backwards?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see only one mistake: it is not $n$ that is divisible by $6$, but $1\pm\sqrt{1+24p}$, but what follows to the mistake assumes this.

Your deduction can be followed backwards easily, so I think that you proved the iff statement.

EDIT:

There is one more gap, and this time it is relevant. You need to mention that $n>0$. Then you can delete the $\pm$ sign at this step:
$$1\pm\sqrt{1+24p}\equiv 0\pmod 6\Rightarrow \pm\sqrt{1+24p}\equiv 5\pmod 6$$

Comment: Ah, should have spotted that mistake. I kind of figured I had to work backwards thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh  right, I had that written down and forgot to mentioned it when I written it here.